# Reconhecimento de voz em Pt-BR

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

Como utilizar Speech Recognition quando meu SO(Windows 8 x64) é em Pt-BR?
Quero utilizar comandos em inglês.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer();
            Choices commands = new Choices();
            commands.Add("hi", "test");

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(commands);

            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

            sr.LoadGrammar(g);

            sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognized);


        }

        void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = e.Result.Text;
        }
```

Porém dá erro no `sr.LoadGrammar(g)`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
>
> Additional information: Nenhum reconhecedor instalado."

Comment: Tu queres usar o reconhecimento em português ou em inglês mesmo?

Comment: Sim, em inglês.

Comment: Uma dica, ao inves de postar fotos do erro, poste o codigo como texto, assim facilita as pessoas e buscadores encontrarem a sua duvida pelo texto da mensagem erro.

Comment: Qual versao do windows?

Comment: Windows 8 x64..

Answer (score 4):

Pra trocar o idioma no método `SpeechRecognizer` voce teoricamente teria que usar desta forma:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SpeechRecognizer sr = new SpeechRecognizer(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

<sub>Leia mais em: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx</sub>

No entanto no Windows em Portugues quando voce acessa este caminho:

- Painel de Controle > Facilidade de Acesso > Reconhecimento de Fala

E exibida esta mensagem:

> O reconhecimento de Fala do Windows nao esta disponivel para o seu idioma de exibicao atual.

Isto porque conforme esta resposta
[answers.microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/reconhecimento-de-fala-do-windows-81/b75dee64-a129-4bef-a81e-75e0ede4c4ec) o *Reconhecimento de Fala* está disponível *apenas* para os seguintes idiomas: **inglês** (Estados Unidos e Reino Unido), **francês**, **alemão**, **japonês**, **mandarim** (chinês simplificado e tradicional) e **espanhol**, desde que o idioma do Windows seja os citados, ou seja, se o idioma do seu Windows for **português**, não irá funcionar.

Comment: Por default, como meu windows é Pt-br, ele já está com o `CultureInfo` em pt-BR

Comment: @JonathanBarcela atualizei a resposta amigo.